# Get ALL values back

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I have 1,825 rows and want to get their associated description back for EACH row (so it should return 1,825 rows back with their number and associated description). In those 1,825 rows, numbers are repeated a ton of times, but I'm wanting to get back the description for each row. In the ICA table there are only 30 ICA's and associated descriptions.

I run the following

```
SELECT ica, ic.Description 
FROM dbo.ICA ic
WHERE ic.ICA IN (
'16569',
'16569',
'16569',
'16569',
'16569',
'16569',
'16569',
'16569',
'16569',
'16569',
'16569',
 etc)
```

*etc (like I said there are 1,825 rows)*

I only get back 30 results though because it's just matching one time for each number in the 1,825 rows, instead of matching on each INDIVIDUAL row. I want to match on ALL of them! How can I accomplish this? I tried joining the `ICA` table against itself, but it still wouldn't do it..

Thank you!

Comment: Is *every* value in the list identical? It's not clear from your description of the problem (or the 11 values you included).

Comment: Part of the question that is missing is where are the 1,825 rows coming from?  You maybe want to clarify that.  My guess is another table which if you added that to your example verses just the list of "ic.ICA" numbers, you would get an answer with the proper JOIN condition to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `values` construct and `left join`:

```
select t.ica, coalesce(ic.Description, '') as Description
from ( values (16569), (16569), . . . ) t (ica) left join
     dbo.ica ic
     on ic.ica = t.ica;
```

However, if you have large no's you can use `temp` table instead of using `subquery` or `cte` for better performance.

Comment: ...or pass the values in via table-valued parameter.

Answer (score -2):

If I am understanding your question correctly, then it should be as simple as this.

```
SELECT ic.ica, ic.Description FROM dbo.ICA ic
WHERE ic.ICA = '16569'
GROUP BY ic.Description , ic.ICA
```